# Push notification in iPhone from outside XMPP server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, notifications, push

I create application and i want to use push notification in it. But application use outside servers (i nave not access to config this servers), e.g. XMPP server(xmpp.org, jabber.org etc.).
As i understand from apple documentation, for get notification, i must send notification with token to APNS from server (my server). Isn't it?  How i can send notification from outside server?

I know it is possible, for example IM+.

Answer (score 1):

its not possible to create it without sending notifications to apple server... but if you think out of the box you can create a layer with your own server which will act like a mediator between your app and your outside server. now you have control over this mediator server here you can send message to apple server to send push notifications to server..